# Multiple condition in where clause

Tags: powershell

When I execute below code, I get an error as : A parameter cannot be found that matches name or. How can I get user list who don't have abc.com or xyz.com in their email address?

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "AQ" -Recursive | where objectClass -eq 'user' | Get-ADUser -Properties *,  "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed", PasswordNeverExpires |

where  mail -notmatch "@abc.com" -or "@xyz.com" | 
Select-Object @{Label = "SAM Account Name";Expression = {$_.SamAccountName}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The curly braces (actually a scriptblock with the filter script) can not always be skipped with `Where-Object`.

You can do `Where-Object objectClass -eq 'user'` but everything that involves more than a single operator requires to be written as a filter script:

```
where {$_.mail -notmatch "@abc.com" -or "@xyz.com" }
```

Now this logic doesn't work, as this is equivalent to the following statement:

```
where {($_.mail -notmatch "@abc.com") -or $true }
```

So your where clause is true, regardless of the result of the `-notmatch` operation. You want two `-notmatch` operations instead:

```
Where-Object - { $_.Mail -notmatch '@abc.com' -and $_.Mail -notmatch '@xyz.com' }
```

Depending on the amount of email addresses, that you want to exclude in your filter script, you might want to use a different approach: Strip the user name from the email address and see, if this address appears in the array of email addresses that you want to exclude.

```
Where-Object { ( $_.Mail -replace '^[^@]+') -notin '@abc.com','@xyz.com','@foo.bar' }
```

Answer (score 2):

for multiple conditions use full syntax:

```
where-object { $_.property -eq $b -and $_.otherproperty -match $a }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some brackets around your `where-clause`:

```
where {objectClass -eq 'user'}
```

And this:

```
where {mail -notmatch "@abc.com" -or  "@xyz.com"}
```

Should look like that:

```
where {mail -notmatch "@abc.com" -or mail -notmatch "@xyz.com"}
```

Please rethink the logic of your second where since it will always be true.

Comment: For simple filter statements in `Where-Object` the curly braces are in fact optional. `where objectClass -eq 'user'` is fine.